# update multiple tables in one go in EF dbcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-1.1

I haven't encountered any where in EF examples, but is it safe to update multiple tables in one go as below

```
using(var db = new MyDbContext(opts))
{
  var record = db.Record.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

  if(record == null) return;

  record.FieldN = ...

  db.Update(record);

  db.Other.RemoveRange(db.Other.Where(x => x.EntityId == id));

 db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe.

`db.SaveChanges()` will execute all your UPDATE / INSERT / DELETE queries in atomic transaction. It will use current transaction or create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but sometimes EF executes what you asked in the wrong order and it explodes, for example deleting 2 things where one is Dependent on the other.

Solution is to just separate those by multiple calls to SaveChangesAsync() (which you should really be using instead of SaveChanges).

Comment: I'm not sure I get how the dependency will affect the deletion? By multiple calls you mean two `using(var db =..)` in the above case?